# React updating state does not change render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a state value that I want to keep track of, declared as such:

```js
const [found, setFound] = useState(0);
```

A simple increment:

```js
  const incrementFound = () => {
    setFound(found + 1);
  }
```

I call this function in a loop as my code works through an array, as such:

```js
values.forEach((item) => {
    doSomething([item]).then(() => {
        console.log("Removed " + item);
        increment();
    });
});
```

And in the return, I render this value like this:

```
<p>Found {found} item(s).</p>
```

However, this value will only ever increment once, even if my code has processed multiple elements.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState is an `async` method and so while it might appear as though every time you call `setFound(found + 1)` the value of `found` is getting updated to be one more than it was the last time you called the setter, it’s likely that the state update hasn’t yet occurred and every time you call it in your for loop the value of `found` remains the same.

You can read more about it in the react docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

The solution here is to pass a callback method to the `setState` method so that when the update happens it can accurately use the previous state value.

```
setFound(current => current + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire loop is executed before React updates state.